# Cosa significa "convogliare" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> Il fatto è che mio padre, Enrico Gassman, **convogliava** l'idea del gigantesco in tutto, statura,  voce, collere, romantici abbandoni, tenerezze.

La mia domanda è sul verbo "convogliare" in questo brano. Ho letto tutte le [accezioni di "convogliare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/convogliare/) ma non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi il significato del verbo "convogliare" nel brano precedente?

Comment: A giudicare dalle tue domande su questo libro, sembra che non ci sia stato un grande lavoro editoriale sul testo. Alcuni termini sono usati fuori luogo o in modo ambiguo. È una cosa che facciamo spesso quando scriviamo, per questo è necessario un processo editoriale che individui errori o forzature.

Comment: @lupalberto: Non credi che si tratti semplicemente di un uso letterario del linguaggio?

Comment: Questo è chiaramente un uso figurato del termine *convogliare* (nel senso di *portare, trasmettere* come nella risposta di A. Darwin) ed è perfettamente accettabile in Italiano.

Comment: Ovviamente è una questione soggettiva, ma secondo me i casi riportati da te non rientrano in questa categoria. Convogliare implica un atto elaborato e volontario, oserei dire ingegneristico. Vuol dire che il padre cercava di impartire una propria idea di gigantesco in tutto quello che faceva? Compresa la sua propria statura? O che in tutto quello che il padre faceva si poteva riconoscere un'idea condivisa di gigantesco? Se si trattasse davvero dell'accezione 3. secondo Treccani: le acque di un fiume convogliano tante cose nel loro corso, non convogliano una sola cosa.

Comment: In altri termini, *convogliare* vuol dire, materialmente o in senso figurato, *creare un convoglio*, in maniera volontaria e, come dicevo, ingegneristica, o in maniera naturale e disordinata come nel caso dell'accezione 3 di Treccani. Ma in ogni caso il risultato dell'azione del *convogliare* non può che essere un convoglio di qualche tipo. Nel caso più astratto, se si *convoglia* un fiume, il *convoglio* non può essere risolto in singole parti, ma è un continuo. Io faccio fatica a pensare all'*idea del gigantesco* come analoga ad un convoglio o ad un fiume, ma ripeto è soggettivo.

Comment: @lupalberto Non credo valga la pena di avere una discussione approfondita sull'argomento, ma questa sfumatura di *atto elaborato e volontario* io non la percepisco proprio. Non voglio dare opinioni sulla qualità del processo editoriale, ma credo che il tuo giudizio sia magari un po' troppo severo. Incidentalmente per me *convoglio* indica principalmente un gruppo di veicoli che effettuano un viaggio insieme, e *convogliare* circa come sinonimo di *trasportare*, più che il significato ingegneristico.

Comment: Un modo sbrigativo per rispondere è questo: _convogliare_ in questo contesto ha lo stesso significato dell'inglese _to convey_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La terza accezione menzionata nel vocabolario Treccani si avvicina al significato di "convogliare" nella citazione di Gassman:

> 3. Trascinare con sé (riferito a corsi d’acqua): i torrenti convogliano materiali d’ogni specie.

Così come un torrente trascina con sé materiali d'ogni specie, Enrico Gassman "trascinava", in senso figurativo, l'idea del gigantesco in ogni suo gesto, atteggiamento, parola.